# Pentaho Kettle PostgreSQL bulk loader error - Can not find target table

Tags: postgresql, pentaho, kettle

I'm trying to setup PostgreSQL Bulk Loader in Kettle but I'm getting the following error:

```
Caused by: org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleException: 
We can not find target table 

    at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.pgbulkloader.PGBulkLoaderMeta.getRequiredFields(PGBulkLoaderMeta.java:618)
```

I can browse the database in the GUI, and the table I'm trying to insert to is there. How can I solve this?

Comment: Well, what's the target table in question?

Comment: can you attach a screen shot of  `PostgreSQL Bulk Loader` step to see the configurations. and your target table field names?

Comment: One thing to remember is that PostgreSQL forces all DB identifier names to LOWER case. You may have to set the "Quote all identifiers" option on the connection.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and after looking at the Postgres logs the problem is rather obvious.

Apparently the "PostgreSQL bulk loader" doesn't properly use the defined connection and uses a hardcoded `postgres` user when connecting.

So to make it work, make sure you connect using the `postgres` user and not any random other user.

This is most certainly a bug in Pentaho Kettle (perhaps even Spoon) but I've not been able to quickly identify the issue in the [source](https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-kettle/tree/master/engine/src/main/java/org/pentaho/di/trans/steps/pgbulkloader) so I'm simply working around the issue for the time being.